# Create matrix with ascending intergers per column with additional shifts and maximal value

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I need to create the following type of matrices in R. Let `m` be the maximal value to increment to per column, and `n` the number of columns of the resulting matrix.

For `m=3` and `n=2`

```
1 0 
2 0 
3 0 
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

For `m=4` and `n=3`

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
4 1 0
4 2 0
4 3 0
4 4 0
4 4 1
4 4 2
4 4 3
4 4 4
```

Does anyone know a nice way how to do that? 
**+1** for the **slickest** answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be valid, unless I've missed something:

```
ff = function(m, n) 
   apply(xtabs(rep(seq_len(m), n) ~ seq_len(m * n) + rep(seq_len(n), each = m)), 
         2, cummax)
ff(3, 2)
ff(4, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Powered by my new knowledge about `cummax` thanks to @AnandaMahto and @alexis_laz, I found a slick one using the Kronecker product

```
apply(diag(n) %x% 1:m, 2, cummax)
```

Comment: +1. Nice, I didn't know about that one. `cummax` was definitely the key to the solution though.... My tests also show this to be faster than alexis's approach... if the milliseconds matter :-)

Answer (score 1):

My suggested approach would be to create an empty matrix, use matrix indexing to fill in your first set of values, and `cummax` to get the rest.

```
myFun <- function(m, n) {
  M <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = m*n)
  M[cbind(sequence(nrow(M)), 0:(m*n-1) %/% m + 1)] <- sequence(m)
  apply(M, 2, cummax)
}
```